# get start of the day in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I used to use `trunc(sysdate)` to get start of the day and `trunc(sysdate + 1)` to get end of the day in Oracle.
But for tests we use H2 DB and this doesn't work.

Are there any lovely alternatives to get start of the day?

Comment: what output do you get when you `select trunc(sysdate) from dual;`

Comment: `trunc(sysdate+1)` gives you the start of the next day, not the end of the day. To get the last second of the day you can use `trunc(sysdate)+0.99999`.

Comment: i'm just using `where TIME_COLUMN >= trunc(sysdate) and TIME_COLUMN < trunc(sysdate + 1)` to get something 'for today'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an possibility to add [user-defined](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [CURRENT_DATE](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_date) in h2.